# Azure ml workbench demo app keep failing during setup

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I installed Azure ML workbench and attempted to create an env with

az ml env setup -c -n  -g  --location

but keep getting failure

```
        "code": "Conflict",
        "message": "SubDeployment: OperationId=08586736946377270318, ProvisioningState=Failed, StatusCode=Conflict, StatusMessage=Template output evaluation skipped: at least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details.
```

How can I look into what this error is exactly, and how to get around it?

Comment: I found some more error message. It says the requested resource is not allowed for my account. Beyond that, I don't know why its not allowed.